# openweathermap API gives no response in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, jasmine

I'm trying to call openweathermap API using this and I don't get a response in the terminal. It shows "I'm inside" and then doesn't give any response. Code is in the images here:

[View the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wuas.jpg)

[View the output of the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrOFv.jpg)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Options = require("../Options/Apioptions");
var request = require("request");
var axios = require('axios');
var ApiRequests = /** @class */ (function () {
function ApiRequests() {
    this.Testing01 = function () {
        console.log("Testing");
    };
    this.Opt = new Options();
}
ApiRequests.prototype.Get = function (req, done) {
    this.Opt.Gita_Token().then(function (options) {
        console.log("I am inside");
        if (req == "GET") {
            request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error)
                    throw new Error(error);
                console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
                done();
            });
        }
    });
};
ApiRequests.prototype.Post = function (req) {
    this.Testing01();
};
return ApiRequests;
}());
exports.ApiRequests = ApiRequests;
//# sourceMappingURL=ApiRequests.js.map
```

Comment: Please don´t post images of you code. Try including them in your post directly.

Comment: Okay! here's it :